# Norm of a matrix evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

In the following A denotes a p×p matrix, and x a p×1 vector.

(a) Is $f_1(x) = ||Ax||^2$ a norm on the space of p×1 vectors? What are the conditions (if any) that the matrix A needs to satisfy for this to happen?

(b) Is $f_2(A) = ||Ax||^2$ a norm on the space of p×p matrices? What are the conditions (if any) that the vector x needs to satisfy for this to happen?

My question is how we evaluate if its a norm on space P*1 , and whats the
difference between a and b. I mean how evaluation is related to the space?

Answer (score 0):

The functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not the same function.

$f_1$ is a function where $A$ is some **fixed** matrix. The function then receives a $p\times 1$ **vector** and returns the number $\|Ax\|^2$.

On the other hand, function with $f_2$, you have a **fixed** vector $x$, and $f_2$ is a function that receives a $p\times p$ **matrix** $A$ and returns $\|Ax\|^2$

For example, if $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$ and $x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$

Then

1. The value  $$f_1\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is defined and equal to $$\left\|\begin{bmatrix}x_1 + 2x_2\\ 5x_2\end{bmatrix}\right\|^2$$
   while $$f_1(\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is **not defined**.
2. The value $$f_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is **not defined** while $$f_2(\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is defined and equal to $$\left\|\begin{bmatrix}a + 2b\\ c+2d\end{bmatrix}\right\|^2$$